# Restrict drag only in one direction

Tags: draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

Using [jQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

How to restrict a draggable to be dragged **only in one direction** ? 
i.e either only top or only bottom when `axis: 'y'`
and either only left or only right when `axis: 'x'`

This means that if I want a draggable `(with axis set to 'y')` to be dragged only to `bottom`, then it should not be able to drag it to top i.e it should remain in its place when tried to drag towards top

This is what I have tried but not working, i.e draggable is still getting dragged in upward direction

```
$('. draggable').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.top'
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
       var distance = ui.originalPosition.top - ui.position.top;

       // if dragged towards top
       if (distance > 0) { 
           //then set it to its initial state
           $('.draggable').css({top: ui.originalPosition.top + 'px'});
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I'm trying to do something similar  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Rj8dJ/24/)

Comment: You're missing the  "I" of India in your profile :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question (other alternative in addition to above answer) so as to help others

Taking a specific case say **allow dragging only downwards when axis:'y'**

```
<div class="draggable">draggable only downwards</div>
```

**css**

```
.draggable {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    background:pink;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    left: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**script**

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    axis: "y"
});    

$('.draggable').on('mousedown', function() {
    var x1 = x2 = $(".draggable").position().left;
    var y1 = $(".draggable").position().top;
    var y2 = ($(window).height() + $(".draggable").position().top);
    $(".draggable").draggable('option', 'containment', [x1, y1, x2, y2]);
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/KLPSC/4/)**

Comment: Just a tiny tip: you could use $(this) instead of repeating $('.draggable'), or store the object in a variable. Thanks Uttara.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1 - with Revert Hack**

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Pk3xC/)**

```
 $('.draggable').draggable({
     axis: "y",
     start: function (event, ui) {
         start = ui.position.top;
     },
     stop: function (event, ui) {
         stop = ui.position.top;

         if (start > stop) {
             $('.draggable').css({top: ui.originalPosition.top + 'px'});
         }
     }
 });
```

**Method 2 - Disable drag without revert**

**[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Pk3xC/5/)**

Basically Method 2 just restrains the draggable element with in a container and moves the container with the draggable element. Have a look, Its surprisingly simple, but effective.

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    scrollSpeed: 25,
    cursor: '-moz-grabbing'
});
$('.draggable').mousemove(function () {
    var x = $('.draggable').css('top');
    $("#containment-wrapper").css({
        top: x
    });
});
```

**Method 3**
Same effect as Method 2, just using the drag function.

**[jsFiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Pk3xC/7/)**

```
$('.draggableDown').draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: "#containment-wrapperDown",
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    scrollSpeed: 25,
    cursor: '-moz-grabbing',
    drag: function () {
        var x = $('.draggableDown').position().top;
        $("#containment-wrapperDown").css({
            top: x
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: U shudn't be able to even drag. What u have done can be acheived by adding 'revert:true'

Comment: @Uttara I'm still working on it, `revert:true` wouldn't work in my case, the draggable element was being reverted off the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Uttara adding `revert:true` conditionally seems to be problematic-[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Pk3xC/1/)

Comment: @Uttara I think I finally have a solid solution, check it out.

Comment: Thanx for your effort :). Have already found a solution long back but didn't get time to post it as an answer.