# How to make drag event move in only one direction in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using drag event for moving an element, but I didn't find a way to make it only move horizontally, it's there any clue for this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict drag only in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609776/restrict-drag-only-in-one-direction)

Comment: @Andam Hi Andam, thanks, but in my case there's no jQuery included, it's only javascript, so this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I have made in javascript for you down below

Answer (score 0):

There is three steps we need to do
first we get the current mouse x position
second we calculate the distance it has move and the direction by `newX = oldX - e.clientX` saying subtract old x with current mouse x this way we get something like -3 or 2 or -1 you see we have the distance the direction - or +
Third step we update the element horizontal position by `element.style.left = (element.offsetLeft - newX) + "px"`

There are more details in the comments in the code. let me know if its not clear

```js
var oldX = 0, newX = 0; // for storing X (horizontal) positions
var element = document.getElementById("mydiv"); // The element you want to drag

// We do the dragging here
function elementDrag(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  newX = oldX - e.clientX; // to calculate how much we have moved
  oldX = e.clientX; // store current value to use for next move
  element.style.left = (element.offsetLeft - newX) + "px"; // update left position
}

// we do this so there is not multiple event handlers
function closeDragElement() {
  document.onmouseup = null;
  document.onmousemove = null;
}

// when mouse down on element attach mouse move and mouse up for document
// so that if mouse goes outside element still drags
function dragMouseDown(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  oldX = e.clientX; // store current value to use for mouse move calculation
  document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
  document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
}

element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;  
  padding: 10px;  
  cursor: move;  
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  Click here to move
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to use the drag event instead of mouse event, is there any solution to that ?